# New or recurrent customer in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataset, which is already sorted by transaction:

```
dataset <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,2,4,6,7,3,2),
                      transaction = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                      amount = c(200,100,50,100,50,300,100,50,100,50))
```

As you can see, each customer has an Id and the amount spent in the transaction.

My question is, how to identify if the customer is a new one in a transaction, or if it's recurrent. A new customer means that is its first transaction, and the next ones are recurrent.

```
recurrence_status <- c("new","new","new","new","recurrent",
"recurrent","new","new","recurrent","recurrent")
```

I have tried so far the following:

```
for (i in 1:(length(dataset$transaction)-1)){
  for(j in 2:length(dataset$transaction)){
    j <- j + 1
    comp <- dataset[j:length(dataset$id)]
    ifelse((is.element(dataset[i,1]),comp),"recurrent","new")
  }
}
```

But it gives me an error due to the brackets. I know that using loops in R should be avoided when possible. Please, any help will be welcome.

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `base R`, this can be done with `duplicated`

```
dataset$recurrence_status  <- c("new", "recurrent")[duplicated(dataset$id) + 1]
dataset$recurrence_status 
#[1] "new"       "new"       "new"       "new"       "recurrent" "recurrent" "new"       "new"       "recurrent"
#[10] "recurrent"
```

Comment: Hello @akrun, thank you for the answer, works fine. Just a question, why you have to add 1? When I tried c("new","recurrent")[duplicated(dataset$id)] it gave me NA NA NA NA, which is equal to the recurrents.

Comment: @Manu The `duplicated(dataset$id)` returns logical vector i.e. TRUE/FALSE.  When I add `+1`, it coerces to `2/1` because the storage mode is 1/0 for TRUE/FALSE.  The index position is 2, 1 is used to populatee the values "new", "recurrent" based on their position in the vector i.e. new is 1 and recurrent is 2

Comment: Now I understand, those are the indexes! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 4):

Utilizing `dplyr`:

```
dataset %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(recurrence_status = factor(+(row_number() > 1), 
                                   levels = c(0, 1), 
                                   labels = c("new", "recurrent")))

      id transaction amount recurrence_status
   <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>            
 1     1           1    200 new              
 2     2           2    100 new              
 3     3           3     50 new              
 4     4           4    100 new              
 5     2           5     50 recurrent        
 6     4           6    300 recurrent        
 7     6           7    100 new              
 8     7           8     50 new              
 9     3           9    100 recurrent        
10     2          10     50 recurrent
```

Comment: Hello @tmfmnk, thank you for your answer and time! Please can I ask just an additional question, why you have to use the plus sign? +(row_number() > 1

Comment: Because `row_number() > 1` returns a logical vector and by `+()` you can convert it to a numeric vector :) it is the same as `as.numeric(row_number() > 1))`.

Comment: Hello @tmfmnk thank you for your kind answer, Now I understand why you use the plus sign.